# How to copy content of an html table row from one table to another using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Here is my code for the First table:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover" id="schedules">
    <thead>
        <th>Schedule Code</th>
        <th>Subject Description</th>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Time</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <button> Copy </button>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <button> Copy </button>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <button> Copy </button>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <td>*content here*</td>
          <button> Copy </button>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Second Table:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover" id="my_schedules">
    <thead>
        <th>Schedule Code</th>
        <th>Subject Description</th>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Time</th>
    </thead>

</table>
```

My jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


    var rows = $("#schedules"),
        copyTable = $('#my_schedules');

    rows.click(function(){
            var row = $(this),
                cloneRow = row.clone();
            copyTable.append(cloneRow);
            row.prevAll().hide();
    });
}); 


</script>
```

It copies the whole content of the first table to the second table. What I want is if I clicked the copy button the specific row only would be copied to the second table.

Comment: is it possible to keep the button in td tag. Else the buttons are  is displaying under body not in the table.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want, I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uan63j3r/2/) for you.

I changed a couple of this, your button seems to be floating nowhere, so i added it in a `td`. Also added a `class` to the buttons for easy selecting.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".use-button").click(function() {
    var html = $(this).closest("tr")
              .clone().find('td:last')
              .remove().end().prop('outerHTML');

    var $schedules = $("#my_schedules")
    $schedules.append(html);
  });
});
```

***EDIT***
If the main table is getting loaded dynamically and you need to click the button you'll have to create a "`delegated`" binding by using `on()`.

```
 $('.use-button').on('click', function() {
    var html = $(this).closest("tr")
               .clone().find('td:last')
               .remove().end().prop('outerHTML');
    $("#my_schedules").append(html);
 });
```

Comment: `outerHTML` contain also `tr`. You don't need to write `tr` in `append()`.

Comment: Still it doesn't work I think because the table is being loaded dynamically using AJAX. I think so.

Comment: Is the main table getting loaded dynamically? if so, you'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using on().

Comment: What is not working exactly? Did you update your html to incl the button class names?

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem. on particular rowclick row copied to second table.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var rows = $("#schedules tr:not(:first)"),
            copyTable = $('#my_schedules');

        rows.click(function () {
            var row = $(this),
            cloneRow = row.clone();
            copyTable.append(cloneRow);
            row.hide();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made changes to some of above structure.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var rows = $("#schedules"),
 copyTable = $('#my_schedules');
 /*
    rows.click(function(){
        var row = $(this),
        cloneRow = row.clone();
        copyTable.append(cloneRow);
        row.prevAll().hide();
    });  
 */
 $('button').click(function(){
     var buttonClass = $(this).attr("class");
     var row = $("#"+buttonClass).clone();
     $('#my_schedules').children('tbody').append(row);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover" id="schedules">
  <thead>
    <th>Schedule Code</th>
    <th>Subject Description</th>
    <th>Room</th>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Time</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
      <td>*1*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <button class="1"> Copy </button>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>*2*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <button class="2"> Copy </button>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
      <td>*3*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <button class="3"> Copy </button>
    </tr>
    <tr id="4">
      <td>*4*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <td>*content here*</td>
      <button class="4"> Copy </button>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover" id="my_schedules">
  <thead>
    <th>Schedule Code</th>
    <th>Subject Description</th>
    <th>Room</th>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Time</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $('#my_schedules').append(cloneRow);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".